No problems have been detected in the workspace: SonarLint
Operating system: Ubuntu 22
SonarLint plugin version: v4.7.0
Programming language: python 3.11
I am trying to use SonarLint for Python Django in VS Code. I am unable to see suggestions from SonarLint in Python code in the editor, nor in the ‘Problems’ section of the Output.
In the Output, I am getting:
‘No problems have been detected in the workspace.’
It does not scan the overall code or show anything new in VS Code. This issue still persists whether I use SonarQube or not.
When I opened serializers.py, I was able to see the logs, but I was unable to see the problems marked in ‘PROBLEMS’ or in the editor.
Output Log File
Update:
I found the solution on the Sonar Community. You can find the detailed discussion on Sonar Community.

I would suggest asking them directly on their Community forum
